# Separate leg transit HKG Chinese Passport?

Tags: visas, transit, chinese-citizens, hkg

I am a Chinese passport holder with US permanent residence. I booked two separate tickets with different airlines, one from US -> HKG (Qatar Airways), one from HKG to China (Xiamen Airlines a day later)

HK website says Chinese passport holder can transit Hong Kong for 7 days without a visa - will I be ok doing this?

Answer (score 1):

In most cases you will be fine; this was the route of choice for many people who wished to return to China when the strict pandemic measures for international flights were in effect.

Mainland passport holders do not even need to hold an onward ticket to be eligible for 7-day visa/endorsement-free transit, since many passengers would choose to take ferry, bus or train for Mainland.

IATA database is a little bit ambiguous on this point:

> Passengers with a passport issued by China (People's Rep.) in transit **(including overland)** to/from a third country for a maximum stay of 7 days.

with the warning that

> Visitors not holding return/onward tickets could be refused entry.

which may lead a strict ground agent to check for an onward ticket. Most U.S. airlines from past experiences do not check.

The wording from TravelDoc is clearer:

> Visa is not required for Hong Kong. Maximum stay of 7 days.
> Passengers holding passports or travel permits issued by China who do not hold onward tickets to a third country may be refused entry, unless the passenger is continuing to mainland China or Macau and has arrived from a third country or region.

Comment: Thank you! I actually unfortunately booked the same flight in reverse (China -> HKG return on Xiamen) and HKG -> USA (return on Qatar) (~26 hour layover in HK)

Do you think the Chinese government/Xiamen will be more strict on understanding if that's a transit vs. a trip to HK since it's two airlines?

Comment: @abc123333 With your ticket and green card there won't be any problems. The Hong Kong route is a very common choice for people living in southern provinces due to the lack of international flight during and after the pandemic. Recently some "high-risk" travellers are inspected more strictly on exit by Chinese border control ostensibly to combat telecom fraud, but showing your green card will be enough to justify the purpose of your trip.